# Can I get 2 set of random number array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
idx=randperm(5)
idx=[1,3,4,2,5]
```

I know this works like that but I'm curious about is there anyway to get something like this.

```
idx=[1,3,4,2,5,5,3,2,4,1]
```

*adding one set of array after one array*

Is there any way to make that?

Answer (score 1):

One vectorized way would be to create a random array of size `(m,n)`, sort it along each row and get the argsort indices. Each row of those indices would represent a group of `randperm` values. Here, `m` would be the number of groups needed and `n` being the number of elements in each group.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
[~,idx] = sort(rand(2,5),2);
out = reshape(idx.',1,[])
```

Sample run -

```
>> [~,idx] = sort(rand(2,5),2);
>> idx
idx =
     5     1     3     2     4
     4     3     2     5     1
>> out = reshape(idx.',1,[])
out =
     5     1     3     2     4     4     3     2     5     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operation:

```
n = 5 %maximum value
r = 2 %each element are repeated r times.

res = mod(randperm(r*n),n)+1
```

Comment: I think OP wants first `n` having random arrangement of `1:n`, similarly for second set of `n` elements and so on. At least by OP words : `adding one set of array after one array` and looking at the expected o/p I thought so.

Comment: @Divakar Ho yeah it's possible, i'm just waiting the confirmation of OP and if this is not the desired output I will delete my answer.